# kde4-config not found?

Tags: 12.04, kubuntu, kde4

Here's my `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
#############################################################
################### OFFICIAL UBUNTU REPOS ###################
#############################################################

###### To use a mirror close to You (I use the fastet ping configured with muon):
# deb http://mirror2.corbina.ru/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe multiverse
# deb http://mirror2.corbina.ru/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse

###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://mirror2.corbina.ru/ubuntu/ precise restricted multiverse
deb-src http://mirror2.corbina.ru/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe multiverse

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://mirror2.corbina.ru/ubuntu/ precise-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://mirror2.corbina.ru/ubuntu/ precise-updates restricted multiverse
deb http://mirror2.corbina.ru/ubuntu/ precise-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://mirror2.corbina.ru/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://mirror2.corbina.ru/ubuntu/ precise-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://mirror2.corbina.ru/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://mirror2.corbina.ru/ubuntu/ precise-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://mirror2.corbina.ru/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse

###### Ubuntu Partner Repo
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner

###### Ubuntu Extras Repo
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main

##############################################################
##################### UNOFFICIAL  REPOS ######################
##############################################################

###### 3rd Party Binary Repos

#### Google Linux Software Repositories - http://www.google.com/linuxrepositories/
## Run this command: wget -q https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub -O- | sudo apt-key add -
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/deb/ stable non-free

#### Kubuntu Updates - https://edge.launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/ppa
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 8AC93F7A
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/ppa/ubuntu precise main

#### LibreOffice - http://www.documentfoundation.org/download/
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 1378B444
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu precise main

#### Medibuntu - http://www.medibuntu.org/ 
## Run this command: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install medibuntu-keyring && sudo apt-get update 
deb http://packages.medibuntu.org/ precise free non-free

#### qBittorrent - http://qbittorrent.sourceforge.net/
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 47B4D1C4
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/hydr0g3n/ppa/ubuntu precise main


####### 3rd Party Source Repos

#### Kubuntu Updates (Source) - https://edge.launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/ppa
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 8AC93F7A
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/ppa/ubuntu precise main

#### LibreOffice (Source) - http://www.documentfoundation.org/download/
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 1378B444
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu precise main

#### Medibuntu (Source) - http://www.medibuntu.org/ 
## Run this command: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install medibuntu-keyring && sudo apt-get update 
deb-src http://packages.medibuntu.org/ precise free non-free
```

I've done `sudo apt-get update`, how come `kde4-config` package is not found?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how come kde4-config package is not found?

Should there be a package kde4-config ?

Ubuntu Packages Search: http://packages.ubuntu.com/

http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=kde4-config&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all

> You have searched for packages that names contain kde4-config in all
>   suites, all sections, and all architectures.
>
> Sorry, your search gave no results

There are packages: kde-config-*

http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=kde-config&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all

The command kde4-config is:

```
NAME
       kde4-config - Prints KDE installation paths

SYNOPSIS
       kde4-config [--expandvars] [--prefix] [--exec-prefix] [--libsuffix] [--localprefix] [--version]
                   [--types] [--path type] [--userpath type] [--install type]

DESCRIPTION
       kde4-config is a command line program used to retrieve information about KDE installation or user
       paths.

       Use this program to determine where the various aspects of the KDE installation reside on your
       system.
```

It is part of the kdelibs-bin and kdelibs5-dbg:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=kde4-config&mode=exactfilename&suite=precise&arch=any

Comment: Oh... Alright then.

Answer (score 1):

I like the accepted answer https://askubuntu.com/a/140214/168991. I helped but didn't completely solve my problem: I saw the error message `sh: 1: kde4-config: not found` printed my many x programs since I installed ubuntu 14 plus Trinity Desktop Environment. I got rid of it by creating a dummy program  `/usr/local/bin/kde4-config` in my path that does nothing but exiting with 1:

```
#!/bin/sh
exit 1
```